# Conditional statement between today date and minus 3 months in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to insert 'NULL' values in a table depending on the date.
If the date is between todays date and 3 months backward (which will be february).
Then I want to update the 'NULL' values into each selected columns.

The Traceback is as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\docs\script.py", line 41, in <module>
     if dt < date_sql < dr3:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'pyodbc.Row'
```

Been strugling for a long time, so really appreciate your guidance as I have tried to find a solution.

Python code is:

```
import pyodbc
from datetime import date, datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
r'SERVER=server;'
r'DATABASE=db;'
)

dt = datetime.today()
dr3 = dt - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3)
print(dr3)

cursor = conn.cursor()

sent_date = cursor.execute("""SELECT TOP 30 sent_date, id
              FROM Department.Customer""")


def fetch_date():
   for row in sent_date:
       r = row
       print(r)
   return r


date_sql = fetch_date()


if dt < date_sql < dr3:
   try:
       value = None
       cursor.execute("""UPDATE Department.Customer SET name=?, address=?, email=?, 
                      phone=?""", (value, value, value, value))

       cursor.commit()

   except pyodbc.Error as ex:
       print(str(ex))

       cursor.rollback()

cursor.close()
```

Output from print(dr3) is:

```
2018-02-28 17:19:50.452290
```

Output from print(r) in fetch_date() function is:

```
(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 22, 10, 21, 36), 1)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 22, 10, 21, 36), 2)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 22, 10, 21, 36), 3)
...
```

Comment: `dt` and `dr3` are `datetime.datetime` objects. BTW, I think that you should have `dr3 < dt` instead of the opposite... But `date_sql` is not. It is indeed a row, and is printed as a 2 tuple date, id. Maybe you could try `if dr3 < date_sql[0] < dt:`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you soooooo much!! =D Give that as an answer and I will gladly accept it. If you have time, I have another problem I want to also solve. We can talk about it in the chat.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot spend enough time to format it as a correct answer, but feel free to use my comment to post your own answer and accept it...

Comment: @SergeBallesta No problem at all, I really do appreciate your help and I hope you still have a wonderful day =D